# Provide a response with view name or HTTP error code

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Im am writing a Spring MVC `@Controller`. On a `@RequestMapping` method I would like to return a View name OR report back a 404 HTTP status code.

How can I continue using Spring View Resolver (for when I need a view) and control response error code **without** throwing an exception?

Comment: why not throw exception? You can process it by your code @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
 @ResponseBody
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)

Comment: Short answer: Because it is not an exceptional event. Long answer: It can be frequent (due to bad API usage), and it would be a situation where throwing an exception is not what I want. The answer right in the spot is simple (return a 404 return code), there is no need to handle an application error (the catch block performed by Spring). After all it is Spring, but it is much more Java, right?! ;)

Comment: ok thx it make sense, going to find my direct setting of responce, in 5 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to solve this is **using directly the provided View Resolver** for both cases. I simply created a view (in my case a .jsp file) for "not found" responses and:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
return "error/" + HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
```

***Extra***: as there can be different ways to trigger a HTTP error response, I also mapped the error pages in `web.xml` to have a similar view for same HTTP error code responses.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/error/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

A little work for what I needed, but it made me set HTTP error handling more accurately in my application.

Answer (score 1):

just raw draft

```
//initialised by init
private Map<String, View> viewsMap;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{path}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public View getResponse(HttpServletResponse resp, @PathVariable String path)  {
    if (viewsMap.get(path ) != null){
        return viewsMap.get(path );
    }
    resp.setStatus(404);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That is quite a hack because of the "strange feeling" null return and the need for a Map. Why not return a 'String'? Is 'null' return only viable with 'View'?

Comment: yes it is hack :), sorry  I do not have time to improve it now. String should be oK. Idea was to use map to decide if it is valid path or not.

Comment: Yes, with String it is also ok:  
    `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);`
    `return null;`  
It does the thing. But somehow it is not yet what I want: `return null` is _hurting_ me and the response body is blank (different from other 404 responses by Spring). Voting answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to implement your own ViewResolver and a View that returns a particular HTTP status code.  You can extend InternalResourceViewResolver (or whatever you're using now).

```
public class MyViewResolver extends InternalResourceViewResolver {
    public static final String HTTP_404_VIEW = "http404view";

    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
        if (HTTP_404_VIEW.equals(viewName)) {
            return new StatusCodeView(404);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return super.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);
        }
    }
}

public class StatusCodeView implements View
{
     private final int code;

     public StatusCodeView(int code)
     {
          this.code = code;
     }

     public void render(Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     {
          response.sendError(this.code);
     }
}
```

In your controller, just return MyViewResolver.HTTP_404_VIEW.

Comment: I was looking for a more streamlined solution. Is this the only way to deal with Spring MVC for my "not that special" case? (I'm also exploring, thank you!)